# Is SQuirreL SQL Client compatible with QODBC?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc, squirrel-sql

Does anyone know if the SQuirreL SQL Client is compatible with QODBC?  If not is there a plugin for SQuirreL to enable so?

Any insight would be appreciated as I have never used either.

Comment: You need a JDBC driver for QuickBooks instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Example of QODBC Driver working with the Java ODBC Bridge Product

Note: Below are some example code from one of our happy customers:

```
// QuickBooks variables
Connection con =null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

// parameters for QuickBooks database
static final String url = "jdbc:odbc:quickbooks";
// "quickbooks" is a System DSN that is the name of the QODBC driver
// On WindowsXP it can be set up at Control Panel > Administrative Tools >
// Data Sources (ODBC)

static final String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
InsertCustomers t = new InsertCustomers();
}

public InsertCustomers() throws Exception {
try {
Class.forName(driver);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
stmt = con.createStatement();
System.out.println("Querying QB customer table");
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer");
```

Comment: Doesn't really pertain to SQuirreL SQL or QODBC directly, but was still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is supported by QODBC - thanks!
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/383/0/how-can-qodbc-driver-work-with-the-java-odbc-bridge-product

Comment: While link can be useful it's better to include the main parts here and then use link as reference as changing the link would make your answer invalid.